# Calculating permutations when an event can end the game

Tags: probability, permutations, lotteries

There are 50 balls. 40 Black and 10 White. You draw balls without replacement and win if you draw all 10 white balls before drawing 4 black balls in a row.

How do I calculate the probability of winning? What if only 9 or 8 white balls need to be drawn to win?

Comment: What do you mean by finding?

Comment: That I get 10 white balls before 4 black balls in a row.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Draw all 50 balls regardless. Then there are $\binom{50}{10}$ ways to place the 10 white balls. In how many is each white ball preceded by a run of no more than 3 blacks?

Comment: Thanks. Yep I got to that point, but then still struggled a little. Sorry, not doing maths day in day out